# SwiftUI access passed view data in sctruct header

Tags: view, graphql, swiftui, parameter-passing

How can I pass data to a view and use it directly in the "header"? All tutorials I made are accessing the data in the view body - which works fine - but I want to call a graphlql method from the UpdateAccountView and than render a view based on the result.

My class for passing data:

```
class Account {
    var tel: Int
    
    init(tel: Int) {
        self.tel = tel
    }
}
```

My main view where the class is initialised (simplified - normally the "tel" will come from an input)

```
struct ContentView: View {

        var account: Account = Account(tel: 123)
        var body: some View {
             NavigationView {
                   NavigationLink(
                        destination: UpdateAccountView(account: account),
                        label: {
                            Text("Navigate")
                        })
             }
         }
}
```

The view I call to do the request and call the next view based on the result
UpdateAccount is taking tel:Int as a parameter.
And here is the problem. I cannot access account.tel from the passed data.

```
struct UpdateAccountView: View {
     var account: Account
     @ObservedObject private var updateAccount: UpdateAccount = UpdateAccount(tel: account.tel)

     @ViewBuilder
     var body: some View {
        if updateAccount.success {
              AccountVerifyView()
        } else {
              ContentView()
        }
     }
}
```

The error:

> Cannot use instance member 'account' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

Update method (GraphQL):

```
class UpdateAccount: ObservableObject {
   @Published var success: Bool
   init(tel: Int){
       self.success = false
       update(tel: tel)
    
   }
   func update(tel: Int){
      Network.shared.apollo.perform(mutation: UpdateAccountMutation(tel: tel)) { result in
      switch result {
      case .success(let graphQLResult):
        self.success = graphQLResult.data!.updateAccount.success
        
      case .failure(let error):
        print("Failure! Error: \(error)")
        self.success = false
        }
      }
}
```

I saw that there is an EnvironmentObject but than the variable become available globally as far as I understood, which is not necessary here.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it in explicit `init`, like

```
struct UpdateAccountView: View {
     var account: Account
     @ObservedObject private var updateAccount: UpdateAccount  // << declare

     init(account: Account) {
        self.account = account
        self.updateAccount = UpdateAccount(tel: account.tel)   // << here !!
     }

     // ... other code
}
```